# Canon Printer lbp251 error 822 for _all_ documents

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printing, printer

Having a problem with Canon printer that will not print any document from a particular computer, regardless of how it is connected-- whether USB,Ethernet, Wifi,or Wifi Direct.  The computer may tell you there was an error, but also may not.  It does not specify it, and nothing new comes up anywhere in Event View.  PC is running Windows 10.  Fully updated, none pending.  Printer works on other Windows 10 machines just fine.

Logging into the printer's web-console, I can see a long list of errors printing from this machine, until you get to the time-frame where it was connected to a different computer, at which point all jobs are successful.

Ran SFC, but had to go, so will check results and test later.

When you attempt to print, the printer will  beep.  If asleep it will wake and go through it's little prep-cycle rolling it's pins.

I have uninstalled and re-installed the driver a gazillion times, tried various flavours of drivers for this printer model from Canon's site, rebooted, shutdown, disconnected power entirely and drooled for 10 minutes.  Windows of course think the device and it's drivers are working famously.

In any case, the error code is 822, every time.  Printer has no USB media ports.  It also initially shows up as both a printer and a scanner, but is not an MFC and has no scanning bed.  Just a basic plain black-and-white laser printer.

If problem is not solved by SFC, what should I try next?

Comment: What file(s) are you trying to print, and are they on a local drive, or elsewhere (like a USB stick)? https://community.usa.canon.com/t5/Office-Printers/MF-644-Cdw-Printer-error-822/m-p/318244

Comment: Any files whatsoever, including a basic Test Print from the Properties dialogue.  This is why it is strange.  Text files, .docx, anything from the browser, absolutely anything, same error code.

Comment: Also, USB is not related.  Not printing from a USB drive, and same error whether printer is connected via USB, Ethernet, Wifi, or Wifi-Direct.